# Play mp4 in chromium with puppeteer, windows

Tags: windows, video, mp4, chromium, puppeteer

I'm developing with puppeteer in node on windows 10.
The problem is that when I open a site playing an mp4 file the browser says me that it is not supported.

I found this package `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree` but it is for Linux!

How can I play .mp4 in Chromium with puppeteer on windows?

Comment: So, why would you want to play mp4 file in a headless browser again? :/

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher Automated screenshots for testing, perhaps!  That's why I'm here ._.

Comment: If it's possible to use OGGs , those work in chromium.

Comment: You can play Webm format in Chromium with puppetter ( VP9/VP8, see https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/ )

Answer (score 13):

The [Puppeteer Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#q-what-features-does-puppeteer-not-support) has an answer for this:

> **Q: What features does Puppeteer not support?**
>
> You may find that Puppeteer does not behave as expected when controlling pages that incorporate audio and video. (For example, [video playback/screenshots is likely to fail](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/291).) There are two reasons for this:
>
> - Puppeteer is bundled with Chromium--not Chrome--and so by default, it inherits all of [Chromium's media-related limitations](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video). This means that Puppeteer does not support licensed formats such as AAC or H.264. (However, it is possible to force Puppeteer to use a separately-installed version Chrome instead of Chromium via the [`executablePath` option to `puppeteer.launch`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions). You should only use this configuration if you need an official release of Chrome that supports these media formats.)
> - Since Puppeteer (in all configurations) controls a desktop version of Chromium/Chrome, features that are only supported by the mobile version of Chrome are not supported. This means that Puppeteer [does not support HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=http-live-streaming).

Therefore, in order to screenshot video playback in Puppeteer, you will need to set the `executablePath` as a separately installed Chrome executable:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/path/to/Chrome',
});
```