# Puppeteer : Unable to play video

Tags: youtube, puppeteer

I can't play Youtube videos with puppeteer. It looks like chromium does not support video playback. What should I do ?

Here's my code :

```js
const puppeteer = require('/root/node_modules/puppeteer/');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjOGhNDX51M');

    await page.waitFor(8000);
    await page.screenshot({
      path: '/var/www/html/test/example.png'
    });

    await browser.close()


  } catch (e) {
    console.log("our error", e);
  }
})();
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976790/play-mp4-in-chromium-with-puppeteer-windows

Answer (score 4):

The chromium that is shipped with puppeteer does not have the codecs required for licensing and size reasons.
You can hook pupeteer to a "real" chrome instance like this :

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
  headless:false, 
  defaultViewport:null,
  devtools: true,
  //args: ['--window-size=1920,1170','--window-position=0,0']
  args: ["--window-size=1920,1080", "--window-position=1921,0"]

})
```

Note the  executablePath option.
Your path may vary.
HTH

Comment: OGG videos work with Chromium => puppeteer.

Comment: Is there is way to hide `Chromium` `window`  it's bit annoying to have it popup, I don't care for it's runs as `headless` or not.