# puppeteer can not take screenshot of react player in nextjs

Tags: node.js, next.js, puppeteer

I have a simple nextjs page which has only one div with simple h1 Tag and React video player component. I want to take a screenshot of my view of h1 tag and video player whatever is playing in that moment using puppeteer. I have implemented puppeteer but it does not take the screenshot of video player instead it returns only h1 tag and blank afterwards.

Actual image I want:

[image: Actual image I want]

Puppeteer screenshot:
[image]

I am using nextjs client side api folder to call puppeteer.

Node js code:

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

export default async function My(req, res) {
  const url = req.query.url;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  const img = await page.screenshot({ path: "output.png" });
  console.log("img", img);
  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
  return res.json("done");
}
```

My component:

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Player = dynamic(() => import("../components/player"), {
  ssr: false,
});
export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    const url = "http://localhost:3000";
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/scrapper?url=${url}`)
        .then((res) => {
          res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    }, 10000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div
        crossOrigin="true"
        id="capture"
        style={{ display: "block" }}
      >
        <h3>Hello</h3>
        <Player />
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "100px" }} id="placement"></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer : Unable to play video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307750/puppeteer-unable-to-play-video)

Comment: No. actually I just want the image of the player does not matter if its playing or not. But I solved it. I will create an answer for it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it. Just added waitUntil Parameter in goto method. Actually the reason was **puppeteer was taking screenshot before the player could initialize itself in the dom**. That's why picture was blank. networkidle0 waits until the component is functional.

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
```